# Sequential numbers via formula - Google sheets - IF & MAX

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I use this formula to find highest value in column A of other sheet, and then add 1 to it to get new unique number for a record ID, and I use...

```
=if(B3<>"",max(Backend!A3:A)+1,)
```

with this formula in cell underneath to get a sequential record number for the rest of the cells.

```
=if(B4<>"",A3+1,)
```

It's used on a sheet where the amount of values in column B shouldn't reach more than 80-100 values, so I have 100 IF statements in column A.

How do I turn these two formula's into an array? Or is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you trying to achieve but here's a try

```
={if(B3<>"",max(Backend!$A$3:$A)+1,);ArrayFormula(if(B4:B100<>"",A3:A100+1,))}
```

Try to provide us a sample with expected results.

Comment: Hi PaulJ, thanks for your help. This works on one cell, but it doesn't fill down. If I change B3 in the IF statement to B3:B, I get circular dependancy. What I was trying to achieve was for new records to check main data (backend) for last/highest record number, and to then +1 for a new unique record ID. I've now taken a script route that adds the formula and autofills to neighbour, then pastes as values. I should probably delete the question?

Comment: Instead of an array with the mustaches {} try maybe to concatenate your results with formula1()&formula2() ? Or divide the formula in 2 columns to attain your expected result ? I think it'll simplify your problem to break it down in multiples pieces.